# Setting up redirects via Craft routes?

Tags: routes, navigation, redirect, redirection

I'm trying to set up redirects for some pages (specifically pages in structure sections that are there purely for structure, which I want to redirect to their first child). Craft's  "routes" seem to be geared towards routing a request to a template. But how can I simply route a request to a different URL?

I know I can use Twig's `{% redirect %}` function, but to be honest I'd much rather just set up all the routes I want redirected outside my template (in order to allow me to avoid (hopefully) unnecessary conditional URL-handling logic in the template). Is this possible at all? If not, is there an elegant way of handling it inside a template?

Comment: Nick, I added the 'navigation' tag to your question. I am not sure if your problem is solved with an approach changing the navigation template only. If not, feel free to remove it again :)

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach: ha, thanks, actually your answer is potentially an elegant alternative solution to the particular problem I'm having, but I guess the question was really meant to be more generally about routing... (I'd still like to know how to easily handle URL re-routing)

Comment: I wouldn't want to set all the routes up in the CP, Nick. So adding some logic to the templates, as you described, is probably the way to go.

Comment: Is there really no way of setting up simple URL redirects in Craft? I'm used to frameworks like FuelPHP where setting up a bunch of routes to handle this sort of thing is really straightforward, and at least *looks* like Craft's "Routes". What confuses me  is why the end of a Craft "route" seems to always be a template rather than a URL... I guess I'd probably put these redirects in the .htaccess rather than the template if I really have to hard-code them - unless there's an elegant way of doing it in the template - but it would be so much nicer to be able to manage these via the admin panel!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "redirect" all parent entries of your structure that have child entries, you could do something like this in your navigation (untested code!):

```
<ul>
    {% nav page in pages %}
        <li>

            {% if page.getChildren()|length %}
                <a href="{{ page.getChildren().first().url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}

        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

If you want to exclude specific parent entries from that behavior, you could do this like so:

```
{% if page.getChildren()|length and page.id('and, not 1, not 2, not 3') %}
```

Comment: getChildren() is being deprecated and relatedTo() is suggested. How would you work this with relatedTo()?

Comment: @Stephen sorry, I somehow missed answering you. You probably use `getChildren` with entries that have no child entries. See the discussion here: ["How to search children with relatedTo param"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/5072/125).