# How to redirect if entry has children?

Tags: redirect

How can i redirect to the first child if an entry has children?

Something like this:

```
{% if entry.hasDescendants() %}
    {% redirect "{{ entry.getChildren().first().url }}" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why do you want to redirect, Johannes? What holds you back from linking to the right entry straight away?

Comment: See this Q/A for what I mean: ["Setting up redirects via Craft routes?"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1488/125)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have twig syntax (`{{...}}`) inside twig syntax (`{%...%}`), which is never right. Does this work?

```
{% if entry.hasDescendants() %}
  {% redirect entry.getChildren().first().url %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: getChildren() has been deprecated. relatedTo() is suggested.

Comment: @StephenCallender I don't think [getChildren()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getChildren) has been deprecated. It is an alias for `getDescendants(1)`

Comment: It is. See here: http://ssdd.d.pr/1hu9D

Comment: I hadn't seen that it was alias for `getDescendants(1)`. I'll try that on my site.