# redirect on a Structure

Tags: structure, routes, routing, htaccess

Client has created /exhibitors but wishes it to point to /exhibitors/partners

Can that be done using routes or should we be looking at htaccess rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a simple redirect, it'll be quicker to do it in .htaccess and not invoke PHP/Craft at all.

Comment: Hey Brad, is this also how you do it with the structure on buildwithcraft.com → Documentation → Installing and Updating?

Comment: No it's not, just checked the urls in the code. :D

Answer (score 2):

We had a pretty similar question already: ["Setting up redirects via Craft routes?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1488/125).

Here's how you could change the code to exchange the parent entry with its first child conditionally. Additionally you can also add a [`redirect`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect) to that child page, in case someone edits the url.

```
{% set linkToChildEntries = ['exhibitors', 'anotherparent'] %}

<ul>
    {% nav page in pages %}
        <li>

            {% if page.slug in linkToChildEntries and page.getChildren()|length %}
                <a href="{{ page.getChildren().first().url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}

        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Of course you can also make this client editable by adding a field to the parent's entry type you then check for instead of managing the to be treated parent entires in the template code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any of the code to hand so I'll have to check it later, but I had a similar need and wanted something I could switch on and off across multiple entries, so I went with a [lightswitch field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/lightswitch-fields) and the following code in the template:

```
{% if entry.firstChildRedirect %}
    {% if entry.children|length %}
        {% redirect entry.children.first.uri %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I've also got a [function in a variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) that when given an entry, either returns that entry, or it's first child, using similar logic.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class YourPluginVariable
{
    public function entryOrRedirected(EntryModel $entry)
    {
        if($entry->firstChildRedirect)
        {
            $child = $entry->children->first();

            if($child) return $child;
        }

        return $entry;
    }
}
```

Which can be used in your templates:

```
{{ craft.yourPlugin.entryOrRedirected(entry).getLink }}
```