# How to search children with relatedTo param

Tags: structure, relations, children

My templates that referenced `entry.children` or `entry.getChildren()` have started throwing deprecation notices:

> Calling getChildren() to fetch an element’s target relations has been deprecated. Use the relatedTo param instead.

What is the preferred way to search for an entry's children — either ALL of its children, or just its direct children — using the `relatedTo()` param?

Comment: What type of entries are these? You should not get these messages for structure entries (see [BaseElementModel, line 540](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/059e8e12ea3886dd1d8b5900a81c22fb562f7759/app/models/BaseElementModel.php#L540)).

Comment: Good catch, @carlcs. My use case is in generating some nav links. (There are a few edge cases where my `entry` may not be a structure entry, in which case it has no children and generates no nav options...)

Answer (score 5):

It appears the preferred way is by using `getDescendants()` — In fact, the `children` property is actually an alias for `getDescendants(1)`. (The parameter specifies a maximum distance (i.e. number of levels) of the child from the parent.)

Comment: Yes, you should use `getDescendants`. But the error came because you applied `getChildren` to the wrong type of elements (`getChildren` was replaced with `relatedTo` for these type of relations at some point).

Comment: Just found it in the [Craft 1.3.2409 release notes](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2409).